# BroadCast receiver with the intent filter of a Widget

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-appwidget

my application is using a widget which is declared in the manifest as follows:-

```
 <receiver android:name=".ui.widgetprovider.DialerWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info_dialer" />
        </receiver>
```

Now what I wanted to know was, that is there any way that I could declare a BroadCast receiver with the same intent filter that of the appwidget provider ?

Something like

```
  <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.WidgetEventListnerReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

So that I can catch the intents being passed to the widget? Is that possible ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.